# Query on signature testing

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, testing, unittesting

I am taking **nonce** as input from users and while testing the signature i am giving the nonce = 1, i want my signatures which is calculated 2 times, first by users, and 2nd by my contract,with same data, will be equal. Testing script is this:

```js
it("provided signature is proper signature", async function(){
            const {multisig, acc4,acc5} = await loadFixture(deployMultisigFixture)
            const to = acc4.address
            const nonce = 1
            const value = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
            const key = "0xdf57089febbacf7ba0bc227dafbffa9fc08a93fdc68e1e42411a14efcf23656f"

            let signature = await multisig.connect(acc5).getSignature(to,value,key, nonce)
            //signature = ethers.utils.joinSignature(signature)
            console.log(signature)
            let _signature = await multisig.connect(acc5).getSignature(to,value,key, 1)
           // _signature = ethers.utils.joinSignature(_signature)
            console.log(_signature)
            await multisig.connect(acc5).verify(acc5.address,to,value,key,_signature, nonce)
            assert.equal(signature,_signature,"not equal!")
        })
```

but in output i getting this where is showing that both signature has different nonce:

```
{
  hash: '0x47d73eab407779b123373278ba77b4d03a1bb898ca7e4cb724ba238dd8462f00',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '0x4fbaa55c6ab30fe7e993fd480ba372e627ee676f2372648de465bd2dc6c79820',
  blockNumber: 16653048,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  confirmations: 1,
  from: '0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "23007746885" },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1000000000" },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "45015493770" },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "29025560" },
  to: '0xe14058B1c3def306e2cb37535647A04De03Db092',
  value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  nonce: 1,
  data: '0x17a2c57a00000000000000000000000090f79bf6eb2c4f870365e785982e1f101e93b9060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000df57089febbacf7ba0bc227dafbffa9fc08a93fdc68e1e42411a14efcf23656f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
  r: '0x60fed132b9a68a00f26b12dd11953d040eeaee0ce88ef00cc88026df7fa5e20d',
  s: '0x7a412fc78631b72385d01eb46cf5254606a33cab2d2342b9f7bedf60007dc7e8',
  v: 1,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 31337,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
{
  hash: '0x6de3fddbaa62e11b569263633ab3b6c1f6fb108f8e18c0fda92437d9a7c8774e',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '0x5e31d613a610889ad7fd766fc8caf5d746f247b1663815a2dd2d38db2e03e151',
  blockNumber: 16653049,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  confirmations: 1,
  from: '0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "20262059284" },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1000000000" },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "39524118568" },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "29025560" },
  to: '0xe14058B1c3def306e2cb37535647A04De03Db092',
  value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  nonce: 2,
  data: '0x17a2c57a00000000000000000000000090f79bf6eb2c4f870365e785982e1f101e93b9060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000df57089febbacf7ba0bc227dafbffa9fc08a93fdc68e1e42411a14efcf23656f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
  r: '0x8fc8330f5654b2853ce24091412b4819cc92cf4c90b34569cecbcc8db9be629b',
  s: '0x79168372817f3ca8726baad6a9f80e7400ecfad8217514d2c9c586c9c923b529',
  v: 1,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 31337,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

if nonce for both signature is not same then my code will not work. How to get same nonce for both signatures?
My other functions from contract looks like this:

```
function getTransactionHash(
        address _to,
        uint256 _value,
        bytes32 _key,
        uint256 nonce
    ) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 transactionHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(_to, _value, _key, nonce)
        );

        return transactionHash;
    }

    function getEthSignedTransactionHash(
        bytes32 _hash
    ) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", _hash)
            );
    }
}
```